# EntityUtils.toString returns weird character string

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an online xml file but there seems to be something wrong with the way the data is shown on the website I'm trying to retrieve it from.

This is my method to get the string of a website back;

```
 public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

When I debug the code the `xml` string for the link I've requested returns this;

[image]

The link in the picture above is the link, so I saved the data from that website into my own xml file and uploaded it [here](http://acewc.net23.net/new.xml) and if I used this link it would work fine but using the 'cloud' link in my picture it returns those weird characters, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Add "UTF-8" parameter at this line:

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```